# linkWithCredential() throws email-already-in-use exception in flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app that makes use of Firebase Auth.  I am following the instructions [over here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking) to link different auth accounts, but I keep getting **email-already-in-use** exception every time I call linkWithCredential().  Here are the steps that I am taking:

First, I sign in the user with a Google account by calling this function:

```
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
      final googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );

      return auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } else {
      throw FirebaseAuthException(
        code: 'ERROR_GOOGLE_LOGIN_FAILED',
        message: 'Failed to login with google',
      );
    }
  }

// call the function to sign in the user using Google
 final userCredential = await signInWithGoogle();
```

Now that the user is signed in using Google, I get a Credential object for email and password like this:

```
final credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password);
```

Now, pass the Credential object to the sign-in user's linkWithCredential() method like this:

```
  // userCredential was obtained when we signed in the user with Google
  await userCredential.user?.linkWithCredential(authCredential);
```

When the linkWithCredential() function gets called, I get the exception email-already-in-use exception!! I have been stuck in this problem for a couple of days already.  Could someone please explain this to me?  The steps that I went through are the same in the documentation.

Here is what my flutter doctor command shows:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.3, on macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-x64, locale en-AE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

I am using firebase_auth: ^4.16.0

In my Firebase project, under Authentication > settings tap, I have "
Link accounts that use the same email" selected

This Firebase project is at least 3 years old.